# Windows XP The specified locale is not supported on this operating system. [ LCID = 16393 ]

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, sql-server-ce-4, lcid

I Use the Sql Server Compact edition 4.0 and have installed on my System (windows 7). From my Solution when i run this works fine basically the line of code

SqlCeConnection.Open() with the connection string as "DataSource='E://S.sdf';" There is No LCID specified in the Connection String .

And this works fine .

But if i run the same on a Windows XP system i get an error 
"The specified locale is not supported on this operating system. [ LCID = 16393 ]"

So i tried changing the LCID in the Connection string "DataSource='E://S.sdf';LCID=1033" it still does not work.

I even tried the SqlCeConnectionStringBuilder.InitialLcid property to 1033 and 1030 it still does not work.

Kindly suggest what am i missing for the Windows XP/Windows Server so that i get this error .

I have installed x86 msi for Windows XP and for my Windows 7 system 64bit installation is done .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the database on your Windows 7 system add "LCID=1030;" to your connection string, this property is a creation time property and has no effect when the database is already created.

Comment: Thanks For your Reply . I have found the problem which is :
I was downloading a compact db file from my system (Windows 7) and using this compact db trying to access it on the Windows Server system . I have now specified common LCID in the connection string .